# How can a mapping have behavior dependent on the presence of a count?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, count

I have this mapping to move by visible line when wrap is enabled

```
nnoremap <silent> j gj
nnoremap <silent> k gk
```

But when I use a count (like `10 j`), I expect to move by actual lines

How to make something like this

```
nnoremap <silent> j (moving_with_repeat ? j : gj)
nnoremap <silent> k (moving_with_repeat ? k : gk)
```

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Title is incorrect. I didn't want to know how to change mapping, I wanted to know whether I'm using command with count

Comment: FWIW: I prefer DJMcMayhem's suggested title, because it's a bit more specific. I think you were misreading it slightly, it's not suggesting that *you* want to know how to change the mapping, it's saying you want to create a *mapping* that changes based on the count.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the title so I updated with what I think is a clearer version. Hope you agree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use expression maps and Vim's predefined `v:count` variable to do this:

```
nnoremap <expr> j v:count > 1 ? "j" : "gj"
nnoremap <expr> k v:count > 1 ? "k" : "gk"
```

This checks the count and then performs the desired operation.

#### Further reading

- `:help :map-expression`
- `:help v:count`
- `:help expr1`