# How can I have my mapping handle a count in a function?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, cursor-motions, count

I wrote the following filetype plugin. It comments out lines in shell scripts by typing `<leader>c`.

The problem is when I execute the mapped command multiple times by writing for example `4<leader>c` then the cursor position doesn't reset like it does when I just do `<leader>c`.

In this case the number in front of the command seems to do the following: it executes the command and then goes to the next line in column 1.

Then the variables that save the current cursor position get overwritten, and the cursor doesn't reset back to the starting position before the first execution of the command.

Is there a way to control this behavior?

Maybe by writing something like `if number_of_commands>1 { do_this }`.

```
map <unique> <Leader>c :call Commenter() <CR>

function Commenter ()
  "get the content of the current line:
  let curline=getline('.')
  "get the column position of the cursor:
  let curcol=col('.')
  "get the line number where the cursor is at:
  let curlineno=line('.')

  let firstchar=strpart(curline, 0, 1)

  let i=0
  while firstchar == " "
    let i=i+1
    let firstchar=strpart(curline, i, 1)
  endwhile

  let i=i+1

  execute "normal " . i . "|"

  if firstchar == "#"
    "typing "_x deletes one character in vim without putting it in register:
    normal "_x
  else
    execute "normal i#\<Esc>"
  endif
  call cursor(curlineno,curcol)
endfunction
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because what you need to do is to use the [`:h v:count`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Acount) variable as shown [in this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14086/how-can-a-mapping-have-behavior-dependent-on-the-presence-of-a-count). Note that in some cases [`:h v:count1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Acount1) is also useful.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!