# Is there a way to map remap 0<C-d> in insert mode

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, indentation

I'm doing a plugin which modify how shift works and remap `<C-d>` in insert mode. Every thing works well but I have a problem with `0<C-d>`. It is a built-in mapping which reset the indentation to 0.
Because I've mapped `<C-d>`, when I type `0<C-d>` I get the behavior of typing `0` followed by `<c-d>` ie the behavior of my plugin, so I end up with a `0` inserting in the text. Is there a way to "detect" that a 0 has been typed just before  ?

Of course I could just inoremap `0<C-d>` to `0<C-d>` (which is the behavior which I want) but it then means that each time I am typing 0, vi enter in mapping mode, which is annoying.

Comment: To add a count to your mapping you probably want to check [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14087/1841), the answers to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20760/1841) or simply [`:h v:count`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Acount)

Comment: Alas, `v:count` is set to 0 where 0 has been pressed or not, so can't be used to differentiate a normala C-D to 0<C-D>

Comment: `v:count1` then?

Comment: Same thing, but returns 1 whatever instead of 0.

Comment: Ah yes I get it now. Indeed I don't know if there's a better option than mapping `0<c-d>`